# #import(ing) non-header files

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As i am following the book on Objective-C, i, my mistake ran into 
`duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ClassName` error, which was quickly resolved once i realized i imported the `.m` file instead of intended `.h`.

This got me thinking:

- In Objective-C, would you ever import a non header file like `.m`?
- Is there a reason Xcode suggests both options (`.h` and `.m`) as part of it's autocomplete?

Comment: look at this question another way; replace objective-c with c (or c++) and see what your answers (and others answers) are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see #import will just replace the import with contents of the file imported. The reason why XCode offers the .m file as part of its autocomplete is because it just grabs every file in the directory to populate the list. A header file could have any extension other than .h but would confuse developers as to its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> In Objective-C, would you ever import a non header file like **`.m`**?

It's uncommon, but not disallowed.

> Is there a reason Xcode suggests both options (**`.h`** and **`.m`**) as part of it's autocomplete?

I guess because there's no reason it shouldn't.